# How to select text with mouse scrolling in vim?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I want to copy some content on remote host in vim, which will last for more than 1 page. But when clicked with `left-click-button` of mouse, and scrolling down, I find I was stuck at the first page.

I know I can use `scp` or first `cat file` then select.

But is there a way to enable mouse scrolling to do such a selection in vim?

Answer (score 6):

Try `:set mouse=a`, should be what you're looking for.

Edit: As a side note, when you try to scroll through the file (as in two-finger scroll on a touchpad, for example), the text may not highlight as you'd expect. However, if you click where you want to start, then simply drag the mouse down, then everything should highlight as the mouse moves and the page should scroll down automatically as well.

Comment: cool ....... (+1)

Comment: I tried that before, but actually, you can't copy the selected content, they are in visual mode

Comment: you can yank them to your clipboard, but on remote host this can't reach your purpose, either

Comment: @Zen, please see my rewritten answer.

Answer (score 3):

Without using mouse you can select lines in `Vim`.

Get out of insert mode, hit one of the options below, and then move up or down a few lines. You should see the selected text highlighted.

```
V       - selects entire lines 
v       - selects range of text
ctrl-v  - selects columns
gv      - reselect block
```

After selecting the text, try `d` to `delete`, or `y` to `copy`, or `:s/match/replace/`, or `:center`, or `!sort`.

Comment: cool! see also `"+y` (+1)

Comment: yes, I know I can select that, but how could I copy these selected lines from remote host to my local clipboard?

Comment: +1 @Zen This is the same issue I have. I can copy & paste text within vim using Visual Selection, but have not been able to figure out how to export vim's selection to my local clipboard.

Comment: @Zen Impossible with Vim itself - unless with a super heavy plugin which carefully examines network stuff.

Answer (score 3):

**X11 Clipboards**

In X11 there are 2 independent clibpoards:

- primary  (paste with the midle buttom) (in vim -- register `"*`)
- clipboard (paste with (CTR+V) or similar; like windows) (in vim -- register `"+`)

**Vim + X11 Clipboards**

The association between `"+` `"*` and the systems clipboards needs a `vim` with
`+clipboard` (see `vim --version` for the active option).

`"+` is the vim register for the system clipboard (CTR-C / CTR-V or similar).

Using @grish and @serenesat we can select some visual text,
and enter

```
"+y
```

As usual, we can use any other vim positioner to define the "copy to clipboard" area. Ex:

```
"+yG    (to save from current position to EOF)
```

This way the text is copied to the system clipboad and can be paste with
the clipbord tecnology, or in a different vim

```
"+p
```

**Vim + X11 Clipboards + ssh**

When remote hosts are involved, you need to use `ssh -XY remoteHost` 
to enable X11 forwarding. This way:

```
ssh -XY remoteHost
vim file   # and   "+yG  or  visual selection and "+g
```

saves text in the clipboard, and it can be paste in the usual ways.

**Vim + ssh**

If nothing else works we can always:

```
vim scp://host/file
```

to edit remote files in local machine...

Comment: @Zen, my previous answer had some incorrect details. I edited it to include some relevant information about cut&paste to remote hosts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move cursor the beginning of what you want to copy.
2. Press v
3. Move cursor to end of what you want to copy by scrolling
4. Press y